# $.getJSON returns array,help needed with $.each

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

i have this code in my view which is in a loop which gives me two rows for console.log

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON("<%= Url.Action("GetTrainingModulePoints" , "Home") %>", function (data) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
   });
   <%: Html.GetQTip("training-module-id-" + module.TrainingModuleId , "With assesment"  , "training-module-id-" + module.TrainingModuleId , Zinc.Web.Extensions.QTipPosition.Bottom, true, "Module Points") %>
```

in my controller:

```
public JsonResult GetTrainingModulePoints()
{
  var currentUser = ZincService.GetUserForId(CurrentUser.UserId);
  IEnumerable<DataModels.Training.UserTrainingPointsDataModel> modulePoints = ZincService.TrainingService.GetTrainingModulePoints(currentUser.UserId);
  return Json(new { result = modulePoints}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

each console.log gives:

```
 LOG: {"result":[{"InteractionType":6,"Points":50,"Name":"China Incentive Program"},{"InteractionType":8,"Points":1,"Name":"China Incentive Program"},{"InteractionType":6,"Points":50,"Name":"India - Q2 Incentive "},{"InteractionType":8,"Points":100,"Name":"India - Q2 Incentive "},{"InteractionType":6,"Points":50,"Name":"China - Q2 Incentive"},{"InteractionType":8,"Points":3,"Name":"China - Q2 Incentive"}]} 

 LOG: {"result":[{"InteractionType":6,"Points":50,"Name":"China Incentive Program"},{"InteractionType":8,"Points":1,"Name":"China Incentive Program"},{"InteractionType":6,"Points":50,"Name":"India - Q2 Incentive "},{"InteractionType":8,"Points":100,"Name":"India - Q2 Incentive "},{"InteractionType":6,"Points":50,"Name":"China - Q2 Incentive"},{"InteractionType":8,"Points":3,"Name":"China - Q2 Incentive"}]}
```

how can i get the interactiontype,name and points seperate?

```
public static MvcHtmlString GetQTip(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string propertyName, string message, string propertyNameOverride = "", QTipPosition position = QTipPosition.Right, bool includeEvents = true, string title = "")
{
  string qtipPosition = String.Empty;

  switch (position)
  {
    case QTipPosition.Right:
      qtipPosition = "my: 'left center', at: 'right center'";
      break;
    case QTipPosition.Left:
      qtipPosition = "my: 'right center', at: 'left center'";
      break;
    case QTipPosition.Top:
      qtipPosition = "my: 'top middle', at: 'bottom middle'";
      break;
    case QTipPosition.Bottom:
      qtipPosition = "my: 'bottom middle', at: 'top middle'";
      break;
  }

  if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyNameOverride))
    propertyName = propertyNameOverride;

  if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
    title = htmlHelper.Resource(Resources.Global.Title.Information);

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.Append(String.Concat("$('#", propertyName, "').removeData('qtip').qtip({content: {text:"));
  sb.Append(String.Concat("'", message, "', title: { text: '", title, "', button: false }}, position: { ", qtipPosition, " }"));
  if (includeEvents)
    sb.Append(", show: { event: 'focus mouseenter', solo: true, ready: false }, hide: 'blur'");
  sb.Append(", style: { classes: 'ui-tooltip-shadow ui-tooltip-yellow' } });");

  return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString());
  }
}

 public sealed class MvcHtmlString : HtmlString
 {

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function:

```
var url = '<%= Url.Action("GetTrainingModulePoints" , "Home") %>';
var jqxhr = $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    $.each(data.result, function() {
        var interactionType = this.InteractionType;
        var name = this.Name;
        var points = this.Points;
        // do something with those variables ...
    });
});
```

Here we are looping over the `data.result` collection in which each element represents an object having `InteractionType`, `Points` and `Name` properties according to the log you have shown. The `$.each` will obviously be executed for each element of the result collection.

---

UPDATE:

After the small discussion we had in the comments section it seems that you are doing something fundamentally wrong here. You are attempting to pass to a server side helper values that you have retrieved on the client using AJAX. That's impossible nr it makes any sense.

So you should be binding on the server. You shouldn't be doing any AJAX requests at all. You should simply call your server side helper and pass it the required parameters:

```
<%: Html.GetQTip(
    "training-module-id-" + module.TrainingModuleId, 
    Model.Points, 
    "training-module-id-" + module.TrainingModuleId, 
    Zinc.Web.Extensions.QTipPosition.Bottom, 
    true, 
    "Module Points"
) %>
```

Now all you have to do is add this `Points` property to your view model:

```
public string Points { get; set; }
```

and inside the controller action that is rendering this view simply set this property. You would first query your data layer to retrieve an `IEnumerable<UserTrainingPointsDataModel>` and then perform some transformation on this array to convert it to a string that you want to be displayed:

```
MyViewModel model = ... get the view model from somewhere
var currentUser = ZincService.GetUserForId(CurrentUser.UserId);
var modulePoints = ZincService.TrainingService.GetTrainingModulePoints(currentUser.UserId);
model.Points = ... transform the original points collection to some string that you want to pass to the helper;
return View(model);
```

Remark: I don't know where you took this `Html.GetQTip` helper but looking at its source code I am horrified. This helper doesn't encode anything. Your site is vulnerable to XSS attacks. Never use any string concatenations to build up javascript and pass variables to functions.

Comment: thank you but can i use those variables outside the $.each?
i tried to do a console.log(interactionType) outside it and got interactionType undefined?

Comment: But what do you need to do with those variables? It makes no sense to use them outside the `$.each` loop because those are only local variables to this context. What is your final goal? You want to perform some transformation on the result, or you want to display them somewhere, or pass them to some other function? You could always access the array by index if you want: `data.result[0].InteractionType` will give you the `InteractionType` value of the first element.

Comment: i need to display it in the Html.GetQTip code I have in my OP where i have the string "with assesment" i must make up an html string to display this in the QTip

Comment: But wait a minute!!! That's a server side helper. You cannot possibly pass javascript variables (that exist only on the client) to something that runs on the server. Remember: server side code executes much before client side. What is this `Html.GetQTip` custom helper supposed to do? Is it generating some javascript code or something?

Comment: yes i see, but this is my ultimate goal, and I have NO idea how to do this, please help?

Comment: But what is this `Html.GetQTip`???? There's no such helper in the standard ASP.NET MVC class library. I cannot possibly help you without knowing what you are doing and what third party libraries you might be using.

Comment: Alright, I see your updated code. But how do you want to pass those values to the helper? I don't see where this helper takes an array argument. For which argument on the server side helper do you want to map the InteractionType, Points and Name properties? Also don't forget that you have an array of those.

Comment: to the "string message" parameter

Comment: But how do you want to pass it? Under what form? You have an array of values. How do you want to map it to a string parameter? You wanna pass them as JSON? Does this helper expect the JSON array?

Comment: oo ok i am beginning to see the issue. i need to make up an html string that contains those values and display it in the QTip

Comment: Yes, and you need to do this inside the controller action. I have updated my answer to provide an example.